# Will a dynamodb GSI double the cost of writes for my table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

A write to the base table also writes to the GSI. If I project all the attributes, will it basically double the cost I currently pay for writes?

Also as an extra question, I have an LSI setup. That incurs costs on all my writes that I have that LSIs key in my items contents. If I don't include that key it will stop writing to the LSI right?

Answer (score 1):

A GSI doubles the number of WCUs you are using (versus the base table only).

LSIs are 'free', and cost you no extra WCUs, as you only write to the base table.

Comment: Isnt a GSI with hash key as the main tables hash key the same as an LSI without the ability to do consistent reads?

Would writes to the GSI be free in that sense? Should I just recreate my table with it as an LSI to save costs then if my GSI hash key will be the same my base table hash key

What did you mean by (versus the base table only?)